# 1D convolution on an audio signal

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, audio

I am using 1D convolution on an audio signal. The shape of the audio signal is (44097,). How can I get only 5 values after the convolution operation? I understand that the output shape depends on the kernel shape and the stride but when I change the weight_1d in my code, it does not change the shape of the output. However, by changing the stride I am able to control the shape of the output. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

sample_rate,audio = wavfile.read('tv1.wav')
print("sampling rate is:",sample_rate)
print("The type of audio value is:", type(audio))
print("Shape of the audio:", audio.shape)

weight_1d = np.ones(3)
strides_1d = 1

in_1d = tf.convert_to_tensor(audio, dtype=tf.float32 )
filter_1d = tf.constant(weight_1d, dtype=tf.float32)

in_width = int(in_1d.shape[0])
filter_width = int(filter_1d.shape[0])

input_1d   = tf.reshape(in_1d, [1, in_width, 1])
kernel_1d = tf.reshape(filter_1d, [filter_width, 1, 1])
output_1d = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.conv1d(input_1d, kernel_1d, strides_1d, padding='SAME'))
print(output_1d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean convolution that gets a signal of (44097,) as an input and outputs tensor of shape (5,). In that case the kernel itself has to be so large that it can fit only five times in input with given 'stide' and 'padding'. You can use the `O=[(W−K+2P)/S]+1` formula, where:

1. O is the expected output size - in your case 5.
2. W is the input size - in your case 44097
3. K is the Kernel size - in your case ?
4. P is the padding - is yours to choose
5. S is the stride - is yours to choose

Based on formula above, `K=[W+2xP-S(0+1)]` and assuming stride=1 and padding=0 you should use kernel of size:

> 44097+2x0-1(5+1)=44091

Comment: Thank you sharing the formula. But my issue is how to set the kernel size in my code.

Comment: @A.Gehani set weight_1d to be the size of whatever the formula produces.

Comment: that doesn't help. That is what confuses me.